# Login screen on my desktop error

Tags: unity, 13.04, login, lightdm, login-screen

When I log in my Ubuntu 13.04 account, my login screen still shows up as my desktop background, making my computer slow.  Recently, I made some changes when I log in, such as removing both "Guest Login" and "Remote Login."  I used the following code:

```
sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

And changed my default login information:

```
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

To this:

```
user-session=ubuntu

greeter-session=unity-greeter

allow-guest=false

greeter-show-remote-login=false
```

I feel like this was the source of the problem so I tried to delete the added lines but the file was "read only."  Is there anyway I can edit the file to fix my problem?

Also, is there anything else I can do so my desktop can return back to normal without the login screen showing?  I just recently downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 a couple of days ago so I'm only a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I strongly advise you not to fiddle around with files that are so relevant to your OS. They belong to root and are read-only for a reason.
2. If you want to skip the login-screen (aka Unity-Greeter), go to the "users" aerea of the system settings and edit your account by switching on "automatic login" (may be labelled slightly different, I'm using the German version of 13.04).

Comment: Manually editing configuration files is one of the normal ways to adjust settings on most Unix-like systems, *including* Ubuntu. This problem happens primarily [due to a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1115886).

Answer (score 1):

see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1173834

Setting "Show desktop icons" ON fixes the problem for me.

You can access this configuration using the "Ubuntu Tweak" utility in 'Tweaks->Desktop Icons'.

Comment: The master bug for this is now [bug #1115886](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1115886).